# Is there a way to set up GitLab renovate bot to automatically resolve composer.lock "content-hash" conflict using update --lock option?

Tags: git, composer-php, renovate

I'm using Renovate Bot on my repository. When it updates any two composer packages, I can easily merge first one, but second one always conflicts on "content-hash" option. What can I do to make Renovate Bot automatically resolve such "simple" conflicts (it is fixable by accepting any of two lines and run `composer update --lock` after)

p.s. Renovate Bot creates MR with `If you want to rebase/retry this MR, click this checkbox` checkbox, but when I click on it or toggle it nothing seems to happen. Is there some kind of delay/interval that I should wait for?

Comment: "When it updates any two composer packages" - what does that mean? How does that happen?